# eclipse上にプロジェクトが表示されない。

Tags: java, eclipse

USBメモリに入っているワークスペース直下のプロジェクトをコピーして、自分のPCのワークスペース直下にプロジェクトを張り付けたのですがエクリプスを起動したときにエクリプス上のプロジェクトエクスプローラ上に表示されていません。
表示させるようにするにはどのような操作をすればよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手動で自分のPCのワークスペースに張り付ける必要はありませんね、
「ファイル」→「インポート」→「既存プロジェクトをワークスペースへ」
→「ルート・ディレクトリーの選択」（そのプロジェクトのディレクトリーを指定）

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクトのインポートして、そのフォルダを指定してみよう